# Python iteration, remove duplicates

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

i want to iterate through list of dictionaries and remove duplicate values

```
example = [
{ 'name' : 'John', 'name2' : 'Mike'  },
{ 'name' : 'Smith', 'name2' : 'John' },
{ 'name' : 'Bob', 'name2' : 'Bob' },
{ 'name' : 'Mike', 'name2' : 'Smith' }
{ 'name' : 'Mike', 'name2' : 'Maria' }
]
```

i need to get result list, like this, without duplicate values:

```
output = [
{ 'name' : 'John' },
{ 'name' : 'Mike' },
{ 'name' : 'Smith' },
{ 'name' : 'Bob' },
{ 'name' : 'Maria' }
]
```

what should i use to get this result? thnks!

Comment: So, you want to get rid of the `name2`s?

Comment: not at all, if name2 is unique, i want add this value to output list

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 2):

Fetch all the names by chaining the `values` of the dictionaries. Then create dictionaries using a `set` of these names.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [{'name': name} for name in set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(e.values() for e in example))]
[{'name': 'Mike'}, {'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Smith'}, {'name': 'Bob'}, {'name': 'Maria'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Leverage the power of Python's **sets** to obtain distinct items:

```
example = [
{ 'name' : 'John', 'name2' : 'Mike'  },
{ 'name' : 'Smith', 'name2' : 'John' },
{ 'name' : 'Bob', 'name2' : 'Bob' },
{ 'name' : 'Mike', 'name2' : 'Smith' }
]

distinct = set()

for item in example:
    distinct.add(item['name'])
    distinct.add(item['name2'])

output = list()

for item in distinct:
    output.append({'name' : item})

print output
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make an empty array, loop through your values and for each one if it's not in the empty array... add it:

```
example = [
{ 'name' : 'John', 'name2' : 'Mike'  },
{ 'name' : 'Smith', 'name2' : 'John' },
{ 'name' : 'Bob', 'name2' : 'Bob' },
{ 'name' : 'Mike', 'name2' : 'Smith' },
{ 'name' : 'Mike', 'name2' : 'Maria' }
]
result = []
for ex in example:
    for name in ex.values():
        entry = { 'name' : name }
        if not entry in result:
            result.append(entry)
print result
```

Outputs:

```
[{'name': 'Mike'}, {'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Smith'}, {'name': 'Bob'}, {'name': 'Maria'}]
```